# Error al instalar node-jt400

Tags: nodejs

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un npm i node-jt400 y el proceso me arroja un error. El ultimo tramo de los errores marca lo siguiente:
Instale Python 2.7 instale tambien las dev tool de windows con el siguiente comando npm install --global --production windows-build-tools,
Tambien tengo instalado el JDK de java, mi sistema operativo es W10, la version de node es v12.2.0, la versión del npm 6.9.0.
Me da la sensación que el problema viene al tratar de compilar algún modulo en C++, ya que los modulos que quedan en rojo con error terminan en .cpp

```
c:\users\esteban\programacion\node js\soportewebtruck\node_modules\java\src\java.cpp(1283): error C2664: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value
(const v8::String::Utf8Value &)': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'v8::Local<v8::String>' a 'const v8::String::Utf8Value &' [C:\Use
rs\Esteban\Programacion\node js\SoporteWebTruck\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\esteban\programacion\node js\soportewebtruck\node_modules\java\src\java.cpp(1283): note: Razón: no se puede realizar la convers
  ión de 'v8::Local<v8::String>' a 'const v8::String::Utf8Value'
  c:\users\esteban\programacion\node js\soportewebtruck\node_modules\java\src\java.cpp(1283): note: No hay disponible ningún operador de c
  onversión definido por el usuario que pueda realizar esta conversión, o bien no se puede llamar al operador
c:\users\esteban\programacion\node js\soportewebtruck\node_modules\java\src\java.cpp(1250): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Get': se declaró d
esusado [C:\Users\Esteban\Programacion\node js\SoporteWebTruck\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\esteban\.node-gyp\12.2.0\include\node\v8.h(3412): note: vea la declaración de 'v8::Object::Get'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code:
1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:257:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Esteban\Programacion\node js\SoporteWebTruck\node_modules\java
gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN SoporteWebTruck@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN SoporteWebTruck@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.11.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo lo pude solucionar, estuve toda la tarde re instalando modulos, las dev tool y al final el problema era la versión de node pareciera que no funciona bien con la ultima versión la 12... baje la LTS versión 10 y algo, y me compilo de una.